# Showing part of a page/code in another page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a code that I use to show a check list in Wordpress in a page as follows:

PHP:

```
<ul class="leftlist">
        <?php
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>
        <li class="todo" id="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" itemage="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_todotime',true)?>"><a href="javascript:;"
        <?php if($all_meta_for_user[get_the_ID()][0]){              
        ?>
        class="strike"
        <?php
         }
        ?>
        >           
        <?php if($all_meta_for_user[get_the_ID()][0]){?>
            <span class="check_box cb"></span>
            <?php }else{?>
        <span class="uncheck_box cb"></span>
        <?php }?>   
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>           
        <?php
        endwhile;
        ?>            
        </ul>
```

This code works fine. However, on a separate page, I just want to show the count of the incomplete list and not the whole check list. How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you want to show only count? if yes then use sessions

Comment: Yes I only want to show counts. Sorry i am abit new to php. What do you mean by sessions?

Answer (score 0):

read this [Sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

if your count value is something like `$count=50;` then  store this in a session like below

```
//you have to call session_start(); in starting of every page where you want to access sessions


session_start();

$count=50;
$_SESSION["count"]=$count;
```

Then in any page you can access this count value as below

in some other page

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["count"];
```

**UPDATE**

Then you can use Cookies

put this end of the onclick function

```
$('.sort, .itemage').on('click', function (e) {
-------
--------
------- all your javscript    

 var count=$(".leftlist li:visible").length;
    document.cookie="incompletecount="+count;
});
```

***in any other page where you want to access this count value***

```
function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
alert(getCookie('incompletecount'));
var incount=getCookie('incompletecount');
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. Sorry I only wanted to show the  count of the items of `<span class="uncheck_box cb"></span>`. Sorry I should have been more clearer

Comment: what does you `<span class="uncheck_box cb"></span>` contains show the data in it

Comment: thanks.please see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5GWz/). This is the html version of the same. <span class="uncheck_box cb"></span> means the check list is incomplete or yet to be done

Comment: i didnt get fiddle link?

Comment: thanks @feroz.. What happens when the brower cookies are cleard?

Comment: There has to be another easier way since all this stored in teh wordpresss database per user. Im sure there can be a way to call information based on the suer id?

Comment: yeah in that case you'll lose the value. then you have to use ajax as you dont want to use this at client side. And i dont have much idea on wordpress sorry